# How can I intercept http requests from an iframe?

Tags: javascript

I programmatically set the URL of an iframe within my web page.
I must know which http requests are triggered from this URL change (URLs for CSS, scripts, images, etc. loading).
I intercepted XMLHttpRequest, but this object is never called...

How can I intercept those http requests?

Is there another way to "load" an iframe and get all triggered URL requests?

Here is my code:

```
(function(xhr){
  var pt = xhr.prototype;
  pt._open = pt.open;
  pt.open = function(){
   console.log('Open called...');
   this._open.apply(this, arguments);
})(XMLHttpRequest);
...
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 4):

An `<iframe />` has a different `window` to the parent window, and as such, when you override `XMLHttpRequest`, you're overriding the one in the parent window, ***not*** the one in the `<iframe />` window.

Unfortunately, the same origin policy prevents you accessing the `window` of the `<iframe />`, so there is nothing you can do about this.

Even if the SOP wasn't in play here, whilst you *could* intercept AJAX requests, there'll be nothing you could do to intercept asset requests (CSS, JS, images).

Your best option is to use a proxy on your server, and route the iframe request through there; re-writing all asset URL's through your proxy instead of direct access (but even then you have impossible edge cases to track, such as JavaScript including other assets etc etc.

Comment: Do you think there is a chance to set up a kind of proxy via JavaScript as shown in http://github.com/philikon/MockHttpRequest ?

Comment: @hollomey: You have no way to inject the `MockHttpRequest` into your `<iframe />` because of the same origin policy, without the use of a proxy server. Even if you did, I'll repeat my answer; *whilst you could intercept AJAX requests, there'll be nothing you could do to intercept asset requests (CSS, JS, images).*.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but if you are still active Matt, how might you go about intercepting the ajax request if you have complete control over the iframe?

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196995/1767316) as long as you can update the iframe code or if you can't,
by injecting some code in the iframe at iframe load event as described [here](http://www.zerogbram.com/2020/12/custom-http-interceptor-hook-to.html).

This typescript sorry might be translatable to javascipt ..

`<iframe [src]="iframeSiteUrl" title="myIframe"  (load)="injectCustomHttpInterceptorHook() id="my-iframe"  #iframeObj></iframe>`

```
@ViewChild(iframeObj, {static: false}) iframeObj: ElementRef;
injectCustomHttpInterceptorHook (){

this.iframeWindow = (this.iframeObj.nativeElement.contentWindow || this.iframeObj.nativeElement.contentDocument);
    let xhrObj =this.iframeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    var parentObj = this;
    this.iframeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
//intercepted here
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
                console.log('load: ' + this.responseText);
        });
        xhrObj.apply(this, arguments);
        const oidcToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(parentObj.localstorageKey));
        const accessToken  = oidcToken.access_token;
        this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + accessToken); 
    }
  }
```