# Intercept iframe message nested iframe, cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a webpage from domain1.com, there I have an iframe of domain2.com and then I have another iframe inside domain2.com of domain3.com

I want to intercept the messages from domain3.com in domain2.com, If domain2.com isn't inside domain1.com then the messages are received correctly, but if I have domain2.com inside domain1.com then messages from domain3.com are received by domain1.com instead of domain2.com. Is there any way to catch those messages inside domain2.com?

The structure is like this

domain1.com has inside iframe src="domain2.com"
domain2.com has inside iframe src="domain3.com"

When I access domain2.com directly it catches domain3.com messages, when I access domain1.com then messages sent from domain3.com are received by domain1.com instead of domain2.com

Comment: What kind of message are you talking about?

Comment: Messages between iframes sent by postMessage and receivend by window.addEventListener("message",fn)

Comment: What is the content of window.opener? Could you demo your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to recreate your iframe hell. Hopefully, this is what you're looking for. This should cover the scenarios you listed above. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

I've also created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/50VfjekXCu1F96YQpYgg?p=preview)

**index.html** (domain1)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  domain 1

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Click to send">
  </form>

  <iframe src="domain2.html" id="iframe" style="display:block;height:120px"></iframe>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
      const [message, domain] = event.data.split('|');
      alert(`domain1: Received ${message} from ${domain}`);
    });

    form.onsubmit = function() {
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(`${this.message.value}|domain1`, '*');
      return false;
    };
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**domain2.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  domain 2

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Click to send">
  </form>

  <iframe src="domain3.html" id="iframe" style="display:block;height:60px"></iframe>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
      const [message, domain] = event.data.split('|');
      alert(`domain2: Received ${message} from ${domain}`);
    });


    form.onsubmit = function() {
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(`${this.message.value}|domain2`, '*');
      return false;
    };
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**domain3.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  domain 3

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Click to send">
  </form>

  <script>
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
      const [message, domain] = event.data.split('|');
      alert(`domain3: Received ${message} from ${domain}`);
    });

    form.onsubmit = function() {
      window.parent.postMessage(`${this.message.value}|domain3`, '*');
      return false;
    };
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly my setup, but in your example, domain 2 is receiving the messages of domain3, while in mine and I don't know why index.html is receiving the messages of domain3.
Maybe is something CORS related? I only control domain2.html, domain3.html is a signaturit.com iframe (in case someone has worked with that service).

Comment: domain 3 post messaging its parent and domain2 is speaking directly to domain3. if you look at domain3 you'll see one slight difference from the rest `window.parent.postMessage`. This allows for you to speak to either domain2 or domain1 (whichever is parent)

Comment: If this fixed your problem could you mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: It did and didn't as I can't control domain3.com so It seems there is no way to receive the messages in domain2.com as it depends of domain3 coding.