# Intercepting react's requests for static assets from inside IFrame

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a simple react app that runs inside an IFrame of another parent webapp. The parent webapp passes along some info on all response headers. For now, I need to extract those fields.

Here's a sample of the requests from my React app (for static assets) that the parent app is responding to

> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /img/user/05.jpg HTTP/1.1 200 3552 - 8.231 ms
>
> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /img/user/06.jpg HTTP/1.1 200 4531 - 8.533 ms
>
> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /img/logo-single.png HTTP/1.1 200 1640 - 7.366 ms

I think I only need to be able to analyse the response headers for these requests, where/how do I get access to these requests/responses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How can I intercept http requests from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184891/javascript-how-can-i-intercept-http-requests-from-an-iframe)

Comment: That approach does look promising but what I am trying to do is the reverse - look at the headers inside the iFrame. Where would that code fit in, in the context of a React app?

Comment: I linked that question because of "there'll be nothing you could do to intercept asset requests (CSS, JS, images)."